# How to use the Rails form tags helper with Vuejs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js

My form helper

```
<%= form_with(url: '/add', method: 'post') do %>
   <%= text_field_tag('name', nil) %>
   <%= submit_tag('Add', disable: 'true') %>
<%end%>
```

generates

```
<form action="/add" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">   
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="a/5xfluAjw...Xb3wY5r+Fg==" />
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add" disable="true" data-disable-with="Add" />
</form>
```

1. It's fine but with vuejs I need to get `v-bind:disable="true"` or `:disable="true"` rather than `disable="true"` How to get this with the form helpers without getting an ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate ?
2. I don't think I need `data-disable-with="Add"` ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I don’t know if it’s the right expectation. Rails helpers won’t generate tags what vuejs expects but there might be some worked around like calling .to_sym on “disable” and pass it as options. Also, did you try any rails-vuejs helper gem that might solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution I wrote `:"v-bind:disable" => 'true'` and now it's working

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can use syntax of rails 5 for data-disable-with="Add" or v-bind:disable="true". just try :"v-bind:disable" => 'true'.